# Trouble with navigation in html

Tags: html, navigation, href

So for the navigation link, I added the local file path in vs code. It worked for a while , but it no longer works.

here is my code.

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="C:/Users/amira/OneDrive/Documents/vsCode_projects/Price King/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="C:/Users/amira/OneDrive/Documents/vsCode_projects/Price King/about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="C:/Users/amira/OneDrive/Documents/vsCode_projects/Price King/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: "no longer works" is not a great description. What are the symptoms? Also don't use fully qualified urls from the file system. Use relative addressing and get rid of the spaces in the URLs or URI Encode them. Just use `href="contact.html"`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use relative addresses. A recommended way to structure your files is below

- Web

  - index.html
  - style

    - main.css
  - about.html
  - contact.html
  - img

    - background.jpg

now you can use relative address like this

> ```
>         <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
>         <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
>         <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
> ```

you can also make a folder for pages and use pages/about.html

Comment: Thanks. It really helped

Comment: @AmiraKhaja can you mark it correct please